# Improving speed of python dblquad and multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing, ray

This is a sample code I am running, which generates a matrix of dimension (`size x size`). The matrix is sent to FFT (over multiple iterations) and their norm is the required result. Since, this is a test run, I set the `size = 256` and the iterations (`zaxis`) to be 3. It takes 1-2 mins per matrix to be processed presently.

Actual production run requires : matrix of `512 x 512, 1024 x 1024` (or maybe more) with about 25 iterations each, and I wonder if I can speed up this python script.

- ***In short***, I generate a complex matrix => assign the non-zero values element by element in a loop => send to FFT => compute norm => save norm in an array. It works fine !
- The heavy work is performed in the following piece of code, where the non-zero values are computed as `val`. Here, 2D integral is computed separately for real and imaginary components. Ideally, I should be able to **perform this on multiple cores**. (*though I think **if assignment of different non-zero matrix elements can be fully offloaded to multiple cores, it would be very efficient.** I am not experienced in multiprocessing. *System spec :* 1700X AMD, 8 cores, 32GB RAM running Python3, Win 10; alternatively Ubuntu system also available with 12 cores, 64 GB RAM )

```
    if (r < (dim/2) ):
        c1 = fy(a,r,x,y)
        c2 = r*complexAmp(a,b,x,y)
        re = I_real ( r ) # double integral, real
        im = I_imag ( r ) # double integral, imaginary
        val=c1 * c2 *(re[0]+1j*im[0])
```

So, my question. Are there any good ways to improve speed of such operations (and hopefully I can learn more about efficient programming in python). For now I am checking  [ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

The following is the **full input script**. Output is shown in bottom.

```
    import time
    import math
    import cmath as cm
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.integrate import dblquad

    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    # DEFINE FUNCTIONS

    def fy(a,b,x,y):
        return (a*b**3+(x/2.5)+y)/50

    def complexAmp(a,b,x,y):
        return ( (cm.exp(-1j*x*y*cm.sqrt(a+b)))/ cm.sqrt( a ) ) *b

    def wrap(r,  rho, phi):
        return cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 \
                     + r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)

    def wrap_real(r,  rho, phi):
        res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 +\
                    r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
        return res.real

    def wrap_imag(r,  rho, phi):
        res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 + \
                    r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
        return res.imag

    rMax = 5

    def I_real (value ):
        return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_real (value,  rho, phi) \
                       , 0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)

    def I_imag (value ):
        return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_imag (value,  rho, phi) ,\
                       0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------

    # TEST INTEGRATION
    print("\n-----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT ----------")
    print (I_real ( 6 ), I_imag ( 6 ))
    print("--------------------------------------------------")

    # parameters governing size and step of grid
    size=256
    depth=10
    step=1.75    # step of grid
    n2 = 1.45
    theta = math.asin(1.00025/n2)

    # complex matrix to keep data
    inp = np.zeros((size,size) , dtype=complex )

    zaxis = np.arange(-60, -10, 20)
    result = np.zeros(zaxis.shape[0])
    n2 = 1.454
    theta = math.asin(1.00025/n2) # update theta
    dim = 16000
    # The main program -----------------------------------------------

    for z in range(zaxis.shape[0]):
        print ("In the loop {0}".format(z))
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(inp.shape[0]):
            for j in range(inp.shape[1]):
                x = step*(i-(size/2))
                y = step*(j-(size/2))
                r = x**2 + y**2
                #print(i, (i-(size/2)),j, (j-(size/2)) )

                b = r*(  math.sin( 1.00025 /n2)) *math.sqrt(2*r**2)
                a = 250/abs(zaxis[z]-r)
                rMax =  abs(zaxis[z])*math.tan(theta)

                val=0
                if (r < (dim/2) ):
                    c1 = fy(a,r,x,y)
                    c2 = r*complexAmp(a,b,x,y)
                    re = I_real ( r ) # double integral, real
                    im = I_imag ( r ) # double integral, imaginary
                    val=c1 * c2 *(re[0]+1j*im[0])

                inp [i][j] = val # substitue the value to matrix

        end = time.time()
        print("Time taken : {0} sec \n" . format( round(end - start,7 )))

        b = np.fft.fft2(inp)
        result [z] = np.linalg.norm(b)
```

---

**Output :**

```
    -----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT ----------
    (-0.0003079405888916291, 1.0879642638692853e-17) (-0.0007321233659418995, 2.5866160149768244e-17)
    --------------------------------------------------
    In the loop 0
    Time taken : 138.8842542 sec 
    [plot]

    In the loop 1
    Time taken : 134.3815458 sec 
    [plot]

    In the loop 2
    Time taken : 56.848331 sec 
    [plot]

    [plot]
```

---

Comment: You might want to try Numba https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: @AKX : Thank you. Will try. I just found that I can use `ray` with `numba`. That sounds even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ray I was able to achieve significant speed up for the above script. The double integral is now solved in a parallel way.

A comparison of time is below.

```
Time in seconds
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+
| loop  | serial version  | parallel with Ray |
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+
|     0 |           138.8 |            34.391 |
|     1 |           134.3 |            34.303 |
|     2 |           56.84 |            32.647 |
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Following is the updated script.

```
from sys import exit
import time
import math
import cmath as cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
import ray

ray.init(num_cpus=6) # initializing ray here

#-----------------------------------------------------------

# DEFINE FUNCTIONS : 

def fy(a,b,x,y):
    return (a*b**3+(x/2.5)+y)/50

def complexAmp(a,b,x,y):
    return ( (cm.exp(-1j*x*y*cm.sqrt(a+b)))/ cm.sqrt( a ) ) *b

def wrap(r,  rho, phi):
    return cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 \
                 + r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)


def wrap_real(r,  rho, phi):
    res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 +\
                r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
    return res.real


def wrap_imag(r,  rho, phi):
    res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 + \
                r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
    return res.imag


rMax = 5
def I_real (value ):
    return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_real (value,  rho, phi) \
                   , 0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)

def I_imag (value ):
    return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_imag (value,  rho, phi) ,\
                   0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)

############################################################

# DEFINE RAY FUNCTIONS

@ray.remote
def I_real_mod (value ):
    out= dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_real (value,  rho, phi) \
                   , 0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)
    return out[0]
#-----------------------------------------------------------
@ray.remote
def I_imag_mod (value ):
    out= dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_imag (value,  rho, phi) ,\
                   0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)
    return out[0]

#-----------------------------------------------------------
@ray.remote
def compute_integral( v ):
    i1 = I_real_mod.remote( v )
    i2 = I_imag_mod.remote( v )
    result_all = ray.get([i1, i2])
    return (result_all[0]+1j*result_all[1])
#-----------------------------------------------------------

# TEST INTEGRATION

print("\n-----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT  : SERIAL ----------")
print (I_real ( 6 ), I_imag ( 6 ))

print("--------------------------------------------------")

print("\n-----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT  : PARALLEL with RAY ----------")
v1=compute_integral.remote( 6 )
print(ray.get(v1))

print("--------------------------------------------------")

#exit(0)

# parameters governing size and step of grid
size=256
depth=10
step=1.75    # step of grid
n2 = 1.45
theta = math.asin(1.00025/n2)

# complex matrix to keep data
inp = np.zeros((size,size) , dtype=complex )

zaxis = np.arange(-60, -10, 20)
result = np.zeros(zaxis.shape[0])

n2 = 1.454
theta = math.asin(1.00025/n2)
dim = 16000

# The main program -----------------------------------------------

for z in range(zaxis.shape[0]):
    print ("In the loop {0}".format(z))
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(inp.shape[0]):
        for j in range(inp.shape[1]):
            x = step*(i-(size/2))
            y = step*(j-(size/2))
            r = x**2 + y**2
            #print(i, (i-(size/2)),j, (j-(size/2)) )

            b = r*(  math.sin( 1.00025 /n2)) *math.sqrt(2*r**2)
            a = 250/abs(zaxis[z]-r)
            rMax =  abs(zaxis[z])*math.tan(theta)

            val=0

            if (r < (dim/2) ):
                c1 = fy(a,r,x,y)
                c2 = r*complexAmp(a,b,x,y)
                o1 = compute_integral.remote( r ) # using RAY decorated integral here
                val=c1 * c2 *(ray.get(o1))
            inp [i][j] = val # substitue the value to matrix

    end = time.time()
    print("Time taken : {0} sec \n" . format( round(end - start,7 )))

    b = np.fft.fft2(inp)
    result [z] = np.linalg.norm(b)

#----------------------------------------------------------
```